# How to print or get the HTTP POST request body in JMETER

Tags: jmeter

How to print or get the HTTP POST request body in JMETER

UseCase: I am running Jmeter from command line to generate Dashboard. For failed cases I need to capture Request Body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the options would be using [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and the following code:

```
log.info(sampler.getMethod() + ' ' + sampler.getUrl().toString())

sampler.getArguments().each {arg ->
    log.info(arg.getStringValue())
}
```

It will print request method, URL and all the parameters along with values to *jmeter.log* file:

[image: JMeter Print Request Details]

in case of [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) `sampler` stands for [HTTPSampleProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html), see the JavaDoc for available methods and fields and [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article to learn more about Groovy scripting in JMeter